# How to integrate NetBeans 8.0 with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am new to develop in php using Netbeans IDE. I use NetBeans 8.0 version. I want to develop a project using Codeigniter framework. But still I was unable to find a way to start a project with Codeigniter template.

When I'm creating a new project, Netbeans ask me to use number of php frameworks such as Symfony, Nette2, Zend2, Doctrine & etc. But there are no anything as Codeigniter.

I tried lots of solutions in stackoverflow. but some of them are for older netbeans versions and others are not working for me.

I downloaded the netbeans CI plugin from https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases

When I was try to install that plugin, NetBeans says that it needs some more plugins to be installed.

How to integrate Codeigniter framework to the NetBeans 8.0..?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Latest NetBeans is 8.2, if you are just starting out it would be better to start with the latest tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2 (Full IDE). I installed both NBM files from the link, that you paste and everything was fine. You need NetBeans with PHP support, if you not want the full IDE. So after installing the 2 nbm files, I can choose the codeigniter framework at the new PHP project wizard.

Regards

Chris

Comment: Yes. I also installed netbeans 8.2 latest IDE. Then I installed both .nbm files from [this](https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/nb-ci-plugin/releases) page. Then added the CodeIgniter.zip folder to the `Tools => Optioins => PHP => CodeIgniter =>BaseFile` location by clicking Add Zip button. 
Then we can select CodeIgniter when we create the project. 

I did that to NetBeans 8.0. But it didn't work.

Thank you Chris.